# file saving in local server but not in live server

Tags: php, yii, yii2-basic-app

I am working on yii2basic template. I am creating a directory when ever a new menu is created by the name of its id(say=13),then i am creating a sub-menu for the menu and creating a Dir for it inside it's menu so the Dir structure is (say=13/1) now in this directory i have to store the image of the sub-menu, i had implemented this work in my local server and it is working as expected but in live server images are not uploaded to the desired directory (say=13/1/tulip.jpg).

Below is the action Iam using in my controller to save the image

```
 $menu_id = $_POST['menu_item'];
 $path= "uploads/$menu_id/";
$model->file=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file') ;
$id= $query->select('id')
            ->where(['name' => $name])
            ->from('submenu')->one();
$dir= $id['id'];
mkdir( $path.$dir', $mode = 776, $recursive = true );
        $newPath="uploads/$menu_id/$dir/";
        $model->file->saveAs($newPath.$model->file->name);
```

Comment: From experience, the most common problem with file uploading is folder/file permissions. Especially if it works in one server but not another.

Comment: @RichardTheobald Thats what i am thinking about but i have allowed all the requiired  permissions(hope so...). any suggestion by u that might be forgotten by me to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be many issues with file uploading on LIVE server

1. Need to set folder/files permissions
2. Server's path is different like for most server you have to use their root path like add prefix to this

   $server_path_prefix = 'www/somename'

Comment: 1. I have already set folder/file permissions. 2.didn't get your second point about adding prefix

Comment: @rahulsnegi At Some servers we have to give root path then folder/file. Are you using LINUX server?

Comment: Yes i am using a linux server for live site

Comment: You can check server path from File Manger ( Root Folder )

Comment: thanks for the help. Yes it was a root path error and a minor syntax error by me in mkdir(). which was ignored by windows compiler but didn't accepted by linux.